# How do I test the current drive letter in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that takes the drive letter the batch file is being run from, and uses it an an IF statement. If the letter is M: for example, it will jump to the label :mSection.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous if "drive letter the batch file is being run from" means "the drive letter where the batch file is located" or "the current working directory". [Dave Cluderay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866638/) addresses the former, and [user10786435's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763570/) addresses the latter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use %~d0 to get the drive letter.
Something like this:

```
IF "%~d0"=="M:" CALL :mSection
```

Comment: This will use the drive letter where the batch resides, though. If you switch drives to, say, Z: and do a M:\blah.cmd then you'll still get "M:" in the batch. You can use the %cd% pseudo-variable to get the current working directory if that is what you intended (and your question sounds like you do). If you need the drive letter from there you can just compare %cd:~0,2% to "M:". Otherwise you can simply jump to the appropriate section by using goto %cd:~0,1%section if you want to easily expand your abtch later on for different drives.

Answer (score 4):

> You can use `%~d0 to` get the drive letter...

It doesn't work whet the .bat is on different drive (somewhere in the PATH.)

I'd suggest:

```
echo %cd:0,2%
```