# How do I get the current drive letter in WIndows 7 CMD?

Tags: system

In Windows 7 the DOS variable %cd% returns the current drive. However when BAT file is started with admin rights (Run as administrator), then %cd% returns "C:\Windows\System32" instead of the current drive. Please, help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: _"In Windows 7 the DOS variable %cd% returns the current drive."_ No, it returns the `C` urrent `D` irectory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test the current drive letter in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866623/how-do-i-test-the-current-drive-letter-in-a-batch-file) or [Windows Batch Script Get Current Drive name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811966/windows-batch-script-get-current-drive-name)

Answer (score 1):

%CD:~0,3% should give just the first three characters (C:)...